# What is the difference between these standard ways to call a function when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, function, call, onload

Whats the difference between these three ways of normally calling a function?
Searched everywhere and found single explanations of each, but not in a comparison of all these three relatieve to eachother. How do these three compare?

A.
`window.onload = LaunchGallery();`

B.
`$(function(){LaunchGallery();}`

C.
`$(window).on('load', function() {LaunchGallery();});`

If there are other standard ways welcome to add and make the comparison more comprehensive

*I'm aware that the `$(document).ready(function(){});` is for JQuery functions only. The scope of this question however is for general, standard, non framework dependant Javascript ways of calling a function into existence during, at or after pageload or any other moment during the lifespan of a webpage).*

Comment: A is broken. B and C depend on jQuery so are out of scope as per the final paragraph of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Why is A broken? By Broken do you mean it should be avoided alltogether in todays modern browsers? I will investigate the two links you provided. Thank you!